# App hangs on Resuming screen after logging in through WebAuthenticationBroker

Tags: oauth, windows-phone-8.1, fitbit

**Update:** This only seems to happen when I run the application in the emulator. Everything is working as expected when I run it on a real device.

---

I am using [WebAuthenticationBroker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br227025) in my app to let the user authenticate to Fitbit via OAuth.

The WebAuthenticationBroker succesffully passes me back the args (i.e. the final URI containing the token and secret), and I am able to make the subsequent call to retrieve the access token from Fitbit. All of this works [as expected](https://wiki.fitbit.com/display/API/OAuth+Authentication+in+the+Fitbit+API).

My problem is that the app then hangs on the "Resuming..." marching ants screen. This happens right after the WebAuthenticationBroker Fitbit login screen goes away and is not related to any code of mine that is executed after that. I have removed all of that code and it still happens.

The call I use to launch the WebAuthenticationBroker is

```
string CallBackUrl = "http://localhost:8080/Fitbit/Callback";

string oauth_token = await GetFitbitRequestTokenAsync(CallBackUrl, ConsumerKey);

string FitbitUrl = "https://www.fitbit.com/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=" + oauth_token;

System.Uri StartUri = new Uri(FitbitUrl);
System.Uri EndUri = new Uri(CallBackUrl);

WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAndContinue(StartUri, EndUri, null, WebAuthenticationOptions.None);
```

I assume I am missing a step after all of this, which is needed to return to my app's page. I have already tried various things I could think of, but I am not sure where and how I need to do this for it to work.

The way I am getting the CallbackUrl with the token/secret args back from WebAuthenticationManager is

```
protected async override void OnActivated(IActivatedEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnActivated(e);

    var args = e as IContinuationActivatedEventArgs;
    if (args != null && args.Kind == ActivationKind.WebAuthenticationBrokerContinuation)
    {
        Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
        var wabPage = rootFrame.Content as IWebAuthenticationContinuable;
        wabPage.ContinueWebAuthentication(args as WebAuthenticationBrokerContinuationEventArgs);
    }

    Window.Current.Activate();
}
```

Help is greatly appreciated! :)

_ rndsum